# Localize text using Properties Resources on Asp.Net WebForms in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, localization, resources

I'm trying to translate the text of a button in my aspx page. I'm using asp.net webforms and I did not achieve it yet. In MVC I can do exactly what I want but in webforms it's being a pain to me.

Here is my resources

[image: My reources]

I'm trying to use it in aspx but without success. I can do it in code behind with this code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = Properties.Resources.BUTTON_SEND;
    }
```

But I really want to do it directly in page

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="HERE_COMES_THE_LOCALIZABLE_TEXT" />
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I do it on Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2017:

1. For global resources right click on Project and select `Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_GlobalResources`.
2. For local resources right click on the folder where is located the file where you want to consume the resources are and select `Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_LocalResources`.

   > For labels and error messages I prefer to use LocalResources. This practice makes the project more organized and easy to modify. Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) for more details.
3. Create resource files and names them as show below:

   [image: Creation]

   > It's possible to create as many **App_LocalResources** folders as you need, but again, the **App_LocalResources** folder, where you will place the resource files (`.resx`), must be in the same folder as the `.aspx`,`.Master` or `.ascx` file.

   Frontend.Master.resx for labels and messages with the default language
   Frontend.Master.**pt-br**.resx for **Brazilian Portuguese** labels and messages.

   > If user change the language of it browser to pt-BR then the page use the `pt-br.resx`.
4. Create resource items. **Name** = Key, **Value** = display text

   [image: Editing]
5. Using local or global resource file:

   ```
   <head>
        <title><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Labels", "HelloWorld") %></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <button type="button">
           <span><%= GetLocalResourceObject("Header_NavButton_Sr") %></span>
           <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ resources:Header_NavButton_Sr %>"></asp:Literal>
       </button>
       <a href="index.html"><%= GetLocalResourceObject("Header_TextLogo") %></a>
       <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" Text="<%$ resources:Navbar_Home %>"></asp:TextBox>
   </body>
   ```

> GlobalResources files generate a `.designer.cs` file. This file generate
>   a static class named 'Labels', if the name of resource file is 
>   'Labels.pt-br.resx', in a global `namespace` called `Resources`. The responsible for this is the 'Custom Tool' `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator` that is defined in resource file properties, and you can access global resources writing `Resources.Labels.ResourceKey`.

**To make LocalResources files static access like as GlobalResources, you can do the following:**

1. Select the local resource file
2. press F4 or right click and select 'Properties'
3. On `Custom Tool` type 'PublicResXFileCodeGenerator'
4. On `Build Action` select `Embedded Resource`
5. After this, rebuild your application or web site. Now you can see that VisualStudio generate a `.designer.cs` file nested with resource file.

**How to use it?**

Following the structure that I create in this answer, we have a LocalResource in the MasterPages folder generating the name space `WebFormsProject2.MasterPages.App_LocalResources`.
If you open the '.designer.cs', in this case `Frontend.Master.designer.cs`, on another text editor, you will see that it generate a class named `Frontend_Master` on the namespace `WebFormsProject2.MasterPages.App_LocalResources` and some static properties with the same name as the resources keys you created in the resource file.
Now you just need to create a reference to this namespace and access properties like `Frontend_Master.Header_TextLogo`.

Example:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="WebFormsProject2.MasterPages.App_LocalResources" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title><%= Frontend_Master.Header_TextLogo %></title>

</head>
<body>...</body>
```

Comment: Why can't I use the Resources inside the properties, like I do in MVC?

Answer (score 4):

Create resources files in "**App_GlobalResources**" folder as below:

[image]

then add your button text in resources files as follows:
[image]

Create resources files for each and every languages you want to transfer the button text to

And in the source code change the button text as below:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Why can't I use the Resources inside the properties, like I do in MVC?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes You can use either implicit localization, wherein ASP.NET fills property values from the resource manager based on matching the resource key to the properties of the control or explicit localization, by creating an expression that retrieves a specific resource from the .NET Framework resource manager. Please refer this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should have done a little  more research...
Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx)

1)Create a folder "App_GlobalResources"
2)Inside the above folder create a resource file "ResourceStrings" and a record with name "Key1"

Then:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="<%$ Resources:ResourceStrings, Key1 %>" />
```

Comment: Why can't I use the Resources inside the properties, like I do in MVC?